# Image doesn't appear in the view in react-native app

Tags: react-native

I have creacte one react-native project and under this folder I created one other floder witch contain one image. I want display this image, so I used the image view, as you see below

`<Image
source = {{
url:'D:\PROJET_TRAQUEUR\React_learn\myfirstreactapp\node_modules\image\photo.jpg'
}}
style = {{width:200, height: 200}}

```
    />`
```

You can also see one imag by clicing the following link , that shows all
[My code and their result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnLRO.png).

But when i ran it, the image not appeared. What is wrong?

Thanks for your helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you use any image in a local then simple pass in `require('//path')`

```
source={require('./assets/icons/abc.png')}
```

or using url you need to pass `uri`

```
source={{uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png'}}
```

also, One more thing if you use a local image then your image should be in your project root folder

Answer (score 0):

As the image is a static resource use require instead of url like this:

```
<Image source={require('D:\PROJET_TRAQUEUR\React_learn\myfirstreactapp\node_modules\image\photo.jpg')} style={{width:200, height: 200}}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using local Image then in the place **url** we need to pass **require**. For example please check below code:

```
<Image
        source={require('./assets/icons/abc.png')}
        style={{
          height: 200
          width: 200
          
        }}
      />
```